# Changing the text color of a div

Tags: jquery, text, colors

I am currently creating a report designer page where you can move, resize and change labels, fields etc.  I have mastered changing the size, weight and alignment of the selected div but I need to change the color.  First when the user clicks the div it needs to get the current color and apply it to a dropdown or color picker and then when the color is changed it will apply it back again.

I don't need code for setting the color I simply need to get the color (which when I do returns something like rgb(0,0,0)), and allow the user to change it, anyone help, all the color picker plugins I found for jQuery have #000000 type codes only so I can't apply rgb(0,0,0) to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get the current color of an element, what you get will vary a bit by browser. The format you've mentioned, `rgb(0,0,0)` can easily be turned into the `#000000` style: `rbg` stands for "red, green, blue" and the numbers are in decimal, so a bit of parsing is all that's required. You might also want to allow for `rgba(0,0,0,0)` where you would disregard the fourth number.

To parse `rgb(0,0,0)` you can use a regular expression:

```
var match, red, green, blue, code;
match = str.match(/rgb\(\s*(\d{1,3})\s*,\s*(\d{1,3})\s*,\s*(\d{1,3})\s*\)/);
if (match) {
    red   = parseInt(match[1], 10);
    green = parseInt(match[2], 10);
    blue  = parseInt(match[3], 10);
    code  = '#' +
            zeroPad(red.toString(16), 2) +
            zeroPad(green.toString(16), 2) +
            zeroPad(blue.toString(16), 2);
}
```

...where `zeroPad` is a utility function that zero-pads on the left:

```
function zeroPad(str, width) {
    while (str.length < width) {
        str = '0' + str;
    }
    return str;
}
```

[Example using text input](http://jsbin.com/akigom)

Comment: How should I catch this if a hex version is returned, check the first character for #

Comment: @user1166905: Sure, that's reasonable.